# How to run mulitple Kafka brokers using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am trying to run multiple Kafka brokers with docker-compose. I am going to use it both in Docker network and on local machine, that's why I am using different ports for brokers:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper_local_dev:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper_local_dev
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka_local_dev_1:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    hostname: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper_local_dev:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper_local_dev
  kafka_local_dev_2:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    hostname: kafka
    ports:
      - "9093:9093"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka2
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper_local_dev:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka2:9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka2:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper_local_dev
```

I am getting an error for the second broker when it's started:

`org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Socket server failed to bind to kafka2:9093: Unresolved address.`

Could anybody assist?

Comment: I followed this guide: https://www.baeldung.com/ops/kafka-docker-setup And it works. Here is the source code: https://github.com/aleksei17/springboot-rest-kafka-mysql/commit/3fea3690923d700388aece4d387064d8d9d3defa

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

- the point is `hostname`

```yaml
...
  kafka_local_dev_2:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    hostname: kafka2
    ports:
      - "9093:9093"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka2
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper_local_dev:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka2:9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka2:9093
...
```

Comment: I replaced `kafka2` with `localhost` and tried to run only with this one broker which uses port 9093. But this did not work. When trying to publish a message, got this error:
`2021-12-09 16:44:57.087  WARN 1839 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected`

Answer (score 1):

You should not change the internal port of kafka broker. It will remain 9092 which is exposed by the kafka container.
Try below

```
kafka_local_dev_2:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    hostname: kafka
    ports:
      - "9093:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka2
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper_local_dev:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka2:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper_local_dev
```